# Pyspark .collect() error - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm getting this error

```
line 23, in parseRating
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

...upon any attempt at `.collect()`, `.count()` etc. So final line `df3.collect()` throws that error, but all the `.show()`'s work. I don't think it's a problem with the data, but I could be wrong.

New to this, really not sure what's going on. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import os
from os import remove, removedirs
from os.path import join, isfile, dirname
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode 

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
from pyspark import SparkContext

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def parseRating(line):
    """
    Parses a rating record in MovieLens format userId::movieId::rating::timestamp .
    """
    fields = line.strip().split("::")
    
    return int(fields[3]), int(fields[0]), int(fields[1]), float(fields[2])
    #return int(fields[0]), int(fields[1]), float(fields[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # set up environment
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .master("local") \
   .appName("Movie Recommendation Engine") \
   .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g") \
   .getOrCreate() \
   
    
   
    sc = spark.sparkContext

    # load personal ratings
    #myRatings = loadRatings(os.path.abspath('personalRatings.txt'))
    
    
myRatingsRDD = sc.textFile("personalRatings.txt").map(parseRating)

ratings = sc.textFile("ratings.dat").map(parseRating)
 
    
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(myRatingsRDD,["timestamp","userID","movieID","rating"])
df1.show()

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(ratings,["timestamp","userID","movieID","rating"])
df2.show()

df3 = df1.union(df2)
df3.show()

df3.printSchema()

df3 = df3.\
    withColumn('userID', col('userID').cast('integer')).\
    withColumn('movieID', col('movieID').cast('integer')).\
    withColumn('rating', col('rating').cast('float')).\
    drop('timestamp')
df3.show()
ratings = df3

df3.collect()
```

Comment: Why are you using RDDs? use `spark.text('personalRatiings.txt')` to get a dataframe, then apply a function over the rows of that

Comment: My Guess is "fields" list is out of range, as it doesnt contain example, fields[3] after the split.

Comment: `show()` prints 20 lines. `collect()` or `count()` would materialize the whole dataset. Error means that (at least) one of the lines further down, beyond 20, is malformed and can't be parsed as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the function `parseRating` and it's about a list index out of range. Probably there's some line in the data that does not have the expected number of fields after splitting by the `::` separator.

How about importing the text file directly to a dataframe specifying field separators and header true/false and modify datatypes of columns with `cast`.

Something like this:

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
          .option("header", "true") \
          .option("delimiter", "::") \
          .load("personalRatings.txt")

df1 = df1.select(df1.timestamp.cast("int"),df1.userId.cast("int"),df1.movieId.cast("int"),df1.rating.cast("float"))

df1.show(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the lines in your textfile may be malformed/incomplete and as a result the `split("::")` may not generate the number of expected fields. You may update your function to check the number of splits before trying to access the indexes. Eg.

```py
def parseRating(line):
    """
    Parses a rating record in MovieLens format userId::movieId::rating::timestamp .
    """
    fields = line.strip().split("::")
    timestamp = int(fields[3]) if len(fields)>3 else None
    userId = int(fields[0]) if len(fields)>0 else None
    movieId = int(fields[1]) if len(fields)>1 else None
    rating = float(fields[2]) if len(fields)>2 else None

    return timestamp, userId, movieId, rating
```

you can even do more [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) if desired.

Let me know if this works for you.